# Grails 3 Error loading CSS when deploying to apache

Tags: apache, tomcat7, web-deployment, grails-3.1

amigos

When deploying a grails 3.1.4 app to a server with apache and tomcat (apache root / is redirecting to grails app in tomcat 8080), the ´asset:stylesheet' is still generating a link to the deployed app (´http://....com/og/assets/application-519a.css´), not to the root (´http://....com/assets/application-519a.css´).

Of course, ´serverURL´ has a valid value

the httpd.conf hast the below chunk of code

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ....com 
    ServerAlias *.....com 
    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/og/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/og/
</VirtualHost>
```

Don't know what I'm doing wrong, any help is welcome, and thanks in advance !

Juan

Comment: I've tryed fallowing [documentation](https://bertramdev.github.io/grails-asset-pipeline/guide/configuration.html) but it`s not worlking

Comment: Also [this](https://bertramdev.github.io/grails-asset-pipeline/guide/configuration.html) . . . not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed up !

In `configuration.yml`, the propper `assets url` configuration is:

```
    . . .
    production:
        grails:
            assets:
                url: "http://....com/assets/"
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: update
            . . .
```

more [information](http://www.grails.org/plugin/asset-pipeline) !

Comment: or, ´url: "assets/"´